# Pass perl user input to xml

Tags: xml, perl

I have a requirement to make template files based on user input taken from a perl script.

When I run perl program it should ask user input and that value should be used inside xml file.

I know to take user input but don't know how to integrate with xml.

Need your precious suggestions.

Thanks,
Sum

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the tutorial [XML for Perl developers, Part 1: XML plus Perl -- simply magic](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlperl1/index.html)

It is more than you need, but will offer you a good introduction to **working with XMLs** in **Perl**